# Rearrange equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can somebody please explain to me how this equation:

$$x = \frac{r}{(r + k)}\cdot1023$$

...gets rearranged to this?

$$r = \frac{k}{(\frac{1023}{x} - 1)}$$

Cheers.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=\frac{r}{r+k}\cdot1023$$
$$\frac{r+k}{r}=\frac{1023}{x}$$
$$\frac{r}{r}+\frac{k}{r}=\frac{1023}{x}$$
$$1+\frac{k}{r}=\frac{1023}{x}$$
$$\frac{k}{r}=\frac{1023}{x}-1$$
$$\frac{k}{\frac{1023}{x}-1}=r$$

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by $r+k$ to get
$$
x(r+k)=1023r
$$
then solve for $r$:
$$
xr+kx=1023r\Rightarrow (x-1023)r=-kx\Rightarrow r=\frac{kx}{1023-x}
$$
and dividing by $x$ (assuming $x\neq 0$) up and down
$$
r=\frac{k}{\frac{1023}{x}-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Invert both sides:

$\displaystyle \frac 1x = \frac {r + k}{r} \cdot \frac {1}{1023}$

Reaarrange,

$\displaystyle \frac{r+k}{r} = \frac{1023}{x}$

$\displaystyle 1 + \frac kr = \frac{1023}{x}$

$\displaystyle \frac kr = \frac{1023}{x} - 1$

One more inversion:

$\displaystyle \frac rk = \frac{1}{\frac{1023}{x} - 1}$

Rearrange,

$\displaystyle r = \frac{k}{\frac{1023}{x} - 1}$